# Is it possible to have a switch/case with mips using a JumpTable for non sequential options?

Tags: assembly, switch-statement, mips

I want to practice using switch/cases and JumpTables in MIPS. Currently, I am able to achieve a similar logic via stacking several BEQ commands after each other. I'd prefer to switch it over to using a single switch statement with cases. Unfortunately, the cases are not in sequential order. There is a user-menu where they enter a character (ascii value) and based on that character, an action occurs. For example, they can choose 'A', 'D', 'N', 'X'. Obviously, that is not in order... I am considering to store an array with the options and treat it as an ENUM (which doesn't exist in MIPS as far as I'm aware) which would solve the non-sequential issue and have an easier time converting the case to the proper character.

This is a bit of my code as of now to help clear things up:
Note that the issue is with the switch/jump rather than the actual logic/action performed in the cases

C++ Example:

```
//switch case sample based on char 
char ch;
cout << "Enter a character: ";
cin >> ch;
switch (ch)
{
case 'N':
    //action to perform
    cout << "N: " << endl;
    break;
case 'A':
    //action 
    cout << "A: " << endl;
    break;
default:
    cout << "You entered an invalid character" << endl;
    break;
}
```

and my current mips solution:

```
.data
 .asciiz 
 enterMenu: "Enter a menu option (N,A,M,D,X):\n"

.word 
JT: N,A,M,D,X #all the possible cases we want to deal with 
 .text 
la $a0, enterMenu #load meu prompt
li $v0, 4 #print prompt 
syscall 

li $v0, 12 #read char from user
syscall 

add $t0, $v0, $0 #move the character to a temporary register (holds switch value)

#switch (k) k = $s5
slti    $t3, $t0, 65    # Test if k < 65 (A's ascii value)
bne     $t3, $zero, Exit # if k < A, go to Exit

slti    $t3, $t0, 90    #Test if k > 90 (Z's ascii value)
beq $t3, $zero, Exit    # if k > Z, go to Exit


beq     $t0, 65, A  # if k = A, go to A
beq    $t0, 68 , D  # if k = D, go to D
beq    $t0, 77, M   # if k = M, go to M
beq    $t0, 78, N   # if k = N, go to n
beq    $t0, 88, X   # if k = X, go to X
```

Edit: The menu an probably be stored as follows:

```
  Cases: .byte  'N','A','M','D','X' #added this in after
```

or as such:

```
JumpTable .word  POW, DIV, MULT, PLUS, MINUS, PRINT, EXIT #different cases 
Operations: .byte  '^', '/', '*', '+', '-', '@', 'x'

EndOps: #hold end spot
```

Then theoretically I should be able to load in the first byte and compare it ... then move on to the next one etc.
The question would then become on how to have them correspond (from the user input) to the JumpTable offset and then to picking cases.

Comment: the only thing that comes to mind would be to have an array of the chars in the order that I want and then do the Jump Table address calculation from that

Comment: Your data examples are broken.  Labels can't go in the middle of directives like `.byte`, between the directive and its operands.  You want `Cases: .byte '^', '/', '*', '+', '-', '@', 'x'`.  (Or `Cases: .ascii "^/*+-@x"` would assemble the same bytes into memory.)  Same problems in your next block.  Assembly syntax is basically line-oriented, so all the operands for an instruction or directive have to be on the same line.

Comment: @PeterCordes MARS seems to be fine with it, but I will change it to wat you commented

Comment: Wow, I was not expecting that.  That's wild, apparently if a line starts with a numeric or character literal, it can just be part of a previous data directive.  And you can even put a `label:` at the start of a line inside a list of operands to `.byte` or `.word`.  On GAS or clang, you'd need a new `.byte` directive at the start of every line containing data.  I'd recommend my way just for style reasons alone even if you didn't care about other assemblers, since `.byte` with an empty operand list, and then a label, and then more operands, is unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Erik for your answer, I was able to figure it out a bit differently on my own:

I am only putting here the most relevant bits of information, you will need to load both arrays into a register and then proceed before doing this. Note that asciiz automatically ends with /0 (null terminator) to know that the string is finished being read (and therefore the user entered case is not in the table)... then send an error message.

These will be in .data

```
Cases: .asciiz  "ADMNX"
JT: .word  L1,L2,L3,L4,L5
```

and this will be in .text

```
la $t2, Cases #get ascii values 

        search:
            lbu $t5, 0($t2) #load in current byte
            beq $t5, $zero, invalid #hit the end of the ascii string, value not found
            beq $t5, $t1, found #found the value 
            addi $t2, $t2, 1 #increment to next byte 
            j search #continue loop
            
        found:
            la $t6, Operations #get ascii values again
            sub $t2, $t2, $t6 
            sll $t2, $t2, 2 #multiply by 4 
            la $t4, JT #load the operation JT labels
            add $t4, $t4, $t2 
            lw $t4, 0($t4) 
            jr $t4 #jump to operation 


#put cases here, then call the respective fns
        L1:
            jal Add #run to function
            j Break #then add the result and print 
            
        L2: 
            jal Sub
            j Break 
    

        Break: #break - as in switch cases
            j Exit  #finished case
```

Comment: If you're happy with that, then super!  It is a fair number of instructions and some data compared to a `beq; beq` sequence.

Comment: @ErikEidt it's certainly more efficient with more cases and it is preferable to branch conditions when the amount of cases exceed 4.

Comment: Regarding dynamic instruction count (instructions executed), the loop approach has 11 instructions overhead, 3 instructions in the loop when case is found and 5 instructions in the loop when case is not found.  So, when found as first case, is 11+3=14 instructions executed, and when found on the 8th case is 11+7*5+3=49 instructions executed.  For the `beq` sequence the instructions executed are 2 for each case including the found case, so is 2 instructions executed for found on the first case, and is 16 for found on the 8th case.  In these terms, the beq sequence is shorter.

Comment: Regarding static instruction sequence length, the loop approach has 16 instructions and the beq sequence has 2 per case, so also 16 for 8 cases, so that makes 8 cases the static code size equality point.  There's no data in the beq sequence so it saves on data as well, making the trade off point further out than 8 cases.  But certainly at some point the loop is worthwhile.

Answer (score 2):

The series of `beq`s is as good as you're going to get for a small number of cases that are fairly spread out (e.g. `A` - `X`).

---

A data table of pointers to code would have to have 24 entries, many going to the default (no match) case.

Code sequence to use the table would:

1. Normalize the input (e.g. subtract 'A'), 1 instruction (`addiu`)
2. Check if greater than table size, 2 more instructions (`sltiu` / `bnez` for unsigned compare)
3. Array index (shift, load address, add) 4 instructions on MARS (3 with an assembler with `%hi(table)` / `%lo(table)` to let you leave part of the table address for the `lw` immediate),
4. Load the data pointer, 1 instruction
5. Branch to data pointer in register, 1 instruction

For a total of 9 instructions (or 8) and a possible data cache miss, though an out of order machine would be able to parallelize execution of the 2 range-check instructions.  (Or an in-order superscalar if you schedule them appropriately.)

---

The series of `beq`'s for your set is 10 instructions (`beq` with a constant is a pseudo instruction that expands to first load the immediate, then compare & branch), though not all will always execute, and they can be ordered for performance.  (Most common first.)

So, I would probably switch to the table version if there were more than 20 or so cases, since at 20 cases, on average, 10 instructions would execute (assuming equal distribution, better if you can order for known distribution.)

If the "default" case is most common, a range-check and/or a bitmap check like `0x12345 & (1<<c)` could rule out being one of the special cases quickly, without going through them all.

Comment: You're overestimating the instruction count for a jump table.  You don't need to separately check for less than 0, that happens for free with a check for unsigned above. `c-='A';` then `sltiu` / `bnez` to check `(unsigned)c < 'N'-'A'`.  So that's 3 total instructions (addiu / sltiu / bnez) to normalize and range-check.  (Also, IDK what you mean about "modern MIPS"; `bltz` as a true machine instruction was part of MIPS I, mentioned in the R3000 manual for example.)  Array indexing: slli / lui / addu, and the low half of the table can be part of the immediate for `lw`.

Comment: Heh, you'd already spotted that as I was typing my comment.  Still, unless I'm missing something, 8 instructions to load a new pointer and `jr` to it if you're clever with address generation with `lui %hi(table)` separate from `lw` with `%lo(table)`.  Otherwise 9, if you do it in a way that's easy to write in asm for MARS or other assemblers without %hi / %lo splits.

Comment: @PeterCordes, yes, you're right. (Of course, optimizing an lui/lw code sequence is hard to do on MARS).

Comment: I fixed your answer, it was still over-counting the range check.  Maybe you were thinking `bgtu $t0, 12, target` would have to materialize the `12` in a register like `beq` would?  It doesn't, `sltiu` is a real machine instruction.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/qj7P1s7vx shows MIPS GCC, and Clang for RISC-V, on a version of this.  (But with a simple store instead of `cout`.)  clang notices that if we're storing, we're storing `ch`, so it does reduce this to a bitmap check, so it doesn't need to branch differently for the different cases.  Essentially turning it into multiple case labels on a `*dst = ch;`.  I left that in as a fun optimization possibility to demo the bitmap idea I suggested as an early check in case the `default` case is the most common.  (Unlikely here since it's invalid, but could be in the general case.)

Comment: @PeterCordes thank you, the issue js the cases ... I removed the action within them for sake of brevity, I'll put the original c++ code through that site as well... if I have an array of bytes (chars), wouldn't it be an issue to move between each of them with the offset and then to translate that to a jump table one... because of the size difference between a byte and a word?

Comment: @APars: Yes, of course I assumed the real use-case would have different actions that can't be reduced to one code path. This answer is assuming you have loaded a char into a register with `lb` (sign-extend) or `lbu` (zero-extend) like a normal person.  (Rather than doing an unaligned word-load that pulls in garbage, or a load of the aligned word that contains the byte.  If you want to do that and shift / AND to extract characters instead of using `lbu`, you certainly *can*, and if done right it will end up with the byte isolated (zero-extended) in a MIPS register.)

Comment: What about something like this .word 
JumpTable POW, DIV, MULT, PLUS, MINUS, PRINT, EXIT #different cases 
.byte 
Operations: '^', '/', '*', '+', '-', '@', 'x'
EndOps: #hold end spot

Comment: Sure, you could write a loop for that.  Best way to compare is to measure.